# Div css style load before the error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am facing a problem which in my code the error `div` loads earlier before it shows the error . could someone please help me to fix that

this is my view file

```
<div class="alert alert-danger mg-b-0" role="alert">
     <?php echo form_error('index'); ?>
     <?php
    if(isset($error)){
        echo 'Your Index number is not registered with our system[enter image description here][1]' . 
        '<br />'.'<a href="http://www.website.com/page.html">Click here to Register</a>'. 
        '<br />';
    }else{
        '<br />';
    }
    ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>           
     </div>
```

here is the screenshot of this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already printed the alert before the check so if there is no $error it will already show an empty alert, you have to check first then echo your whole divs inside:

```
<?php if (isset($error)): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <?php echo $error ?> <!-- or write whatever you want -->
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```